# JavaFX Media Streaming Over Network

Tags: java, video-streaming, javafx-2

I am new to using JavaFX, and I am trying to just get a basic program working so that I can display video from a networked http H.264 stream. When I load the program it gives me a blank screen. Any suggestions? I have tried both using the file and the direct string, the file closes with a media not found error, and the string shows just a blank screen.

The url works fine in VLC.

Here is the code I have so far. Most of it is from an Oracle tutorial.

```
// Create and set the Scene.
 Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 540, 209);
 primaryStage.setScene(scene);

 // Name and display the Stage.
 primaryStage.setTitle("Hello Media");
 primaryStage.show();

 // Create the media source.
 File file = new File("http://10.10.80.39:8080/h264/cam1/temp.ts");
 String source = file.toURI().toASCIIString();
 Media media = new Media("http://10.10.80.39:8080/h264/cam1/temp.ts");

 // Create the player and set to play automatically.
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
 mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

 // Create the view and add it to the Scene.
 MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
 ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(mediaView);
```

Comment: Is your setup in conformance with the supported media encoding/containers/protocols/metadata tags and http live streaming characteristics [documented for JavaFX media](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html)? Do you have comprehensive error handling (example is also in media javadoc) to debug what went wrong and add error output to your question?  Does your client meet the [supported configuration requirement for JavaFX media playback](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html)?